# Why is this function not pure?

Tags: c, function, language-agnostic

In the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function#Impure_functions it says that the following function is not pure.

```
int f(int* x) 
{
    return *x;
}
```

Why is that? The function would return the same value for the same argument right? Would it be considered pure if it was a non-mutable reference, as in the following?

```
int f2(const int* x) 
{
    return *x;
}
```

Comment: My best quick guess is that, given the same pointer, it might return different values at different times depending not on the value of the pointer but on the contents of what it is pointing at. The definition of 'pure function' on Wikipedia says a function is pure if "[i]ts return value is the same for the same arguments (no variation with local static variables, non-local variables, mutable reference arguments or input streams from I/O devices)." I think the pointer points at a non-local variable, and/or is a mutable reference argument, but I might be misunderstanding the terminology.

Comment: Indeed, the notation above the example says "because of return value variation with a mutable reference argument".  Adding `const` won't help; it simply says the function won't modify the value that `x` points at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f` isn't pure because its return value isn't necessary the same for the same arguments. You could call `f` twice with the same inputs and get different outputs. The following program demonstrates this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int i = 3;
   int * const x = &i;
   printf("%d\n", f(x));
   i = 4;
   printf("%d\n", f(x));
   return 0;
}
```

Because `x` doesn't change between the two calls, the second call to `f(x)` could be optimized away (in favour of reusing the result from the first call) if `f` was pure. Obviously, that could produce the wrong result, so `f` isn't pure.

`f2` isn't pure for the same reason.

Comment: that definition doesn't make much sense for a single-threaded language without pointers, like JavaScript, right? In JavaScript, I wouldn't consider `x` to be the same anymore.

Comment: @mb21, How can you claim that you wouldn't consider the pointer to the be same anymore if this was JS when JS has no pointers? You're not making any sense.

Comment: @mb21, C is not a single-threaded language. It's irrelevant anyway.

Comment: @mb21, That would also be impure for the same reason. There is a variation in the return value due to a mutable reference argument.

Comment: I've opened a new question to expand my argument :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65872468/is-this-javascript-function-taking-a-mutable-reference-argument-a-pure-functio

Answer (score 2):

Rule 1 says:

> Its return value is the same for the same **arguments** (no variation with local static variables, non-local variables, mutable reference arguments or input streams from I/O devices).

The point is that the argument **is not** the value pointed by `x` but rather the address of the pointer. You're passing an address to the function.

Since you can change the pointed data and pass the same address then you have different return values.

Of course this wouldn't be true if `f` or `f2` returned `int*` instead that `int`. In that case the same argument would lead to the same return value.