# Is this JavaScript function, taking a mutable reference argument, a pure function?

Tags: javascript, function, functional-programming, purely-functional

I have the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56916347/), but in the context of JavaScript.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function):

> [a pure function's] return value is the same for the *same* arguments

It's further claimed there that a pure function is not allowed to have a variation in return value with "mutable reference arguments". In JavaScript, every normal object is passed as a "mutable reference argument". Consider the following example:

```js
const f = (arr) => arr.length

const x = []
console.log( f(x) ) // 0
x.push(1);
console.log( f(x) ) // 1
```

Is the above proof that `f` is impure?
Or would you argue that we're not calling `f` with the "same" argument in the two cases?

I can see how it would make sense to call `f` impure in a language/environment where other threads could potentially mess with the mutable reference argument while `f` is executing. But since `f` is not `async`, there is no way for this to happen. `x` is going to stay the same from the moment `f` is called to when it's done executing. (If I'm understanding correctly, this interpretation seems to be supported by the definition of "same" put forth in § 4.1 of [Verifiable Functional Purity in Java](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Edaw/papers/pure-ccs08.pdf).)

Or am I missing something? Is there an example in JavaScript where a function containing no asynchronous code loses the property of [referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency) simply because it's taking a mutable reference, but it would be pure if we used e.g. an Immutable.js data structure instead?

Comment: Does the definition say “same object”, or “same value”…? Is the list the same value in both cases? What if you serialized and unserialized it? What if you replaced the argument with a literal instead of a variable?

Comment: That's the thing, the definition doesn't say what they mean with "same". Judging from your questions, you seem to agree with me that "same serialization" would make more sense than "same object reference"?

Comment: In Javascript objects obtain identity through their references. This referential identity property is opposed to referential transparency in purely functional langs. So formally, there are no pure functions in Javascript, but you can get the desired behavior by convention and confidence.

Comment: If you stick to the purity convention than you can be pretty confident that `f` is a pure function.

Comment: @scriptum "formally, there are no pure functions in Javascript" – that reasoning would surely to Java as well? But have you checked out the paper I linked to?

Comment: I am reading the paper. Interesting read (+1)

Comment: at least in js, there may be functions which are pure (among those which take as arguments frozen objects, primitive types)

Comment: From the paper: *"There is not a single obviously right answer to these questions. Determinism is thus a parameterized property:  **given a definition of what it means for arguments to be equivalent**, a method is deterministic if all calls with **equivalent** arguments return results that are indistinguishable from within the language"*.

Comment: @trincot yes, but the definition of "equivalent" they put forth in § 4.1 seems to say that we're not calling `f` with "equivalent" arguments in the two cases in my example.

Comment: One of the reasons to identify pure functions is to remove unnecessary calls to them or reorder code. You would have to consider the two `x` to be different for the function to be considered pure. If that's what the analyser does, fine. But without that context, that function isn't pure.

Comment: So is this not a matter of opinion? The paper itself suggests that a definition of equivalence is a choice to be made (within certain boundaries). So are you asking for a choice? I guess this will lead to opinionated answers.

Comment: Redux developers would consider `f = () => []` to be "pure" even though `f() === f()` is false because `[] === []` is false.  So you definitely have to define what it means for things to be equivalent within the context of how you are going to use them. Also consider what happens if you just bake in the mutation as a property getter: `x = { get length() { return global++; } }`  Then `f(x) == f(x)` can easily be false by setting `global` to `1` beforehand.  So `arr => arr.length` is only as pure as `g => g()`

Comment: If we take the definition of "same" from the paper, which seems to boil down to something akin to `JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b)` (leaving aside cases like NaN, etc.), and assume nobody has tampered with any prototypes etc, then taking a mutable reference argument seems perfectly safe – as long as you're not using any asynchronous code – right?

Comment: Or perhaps [lodash's `_.isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual) is an even more useful definition of "same" in practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When taking the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) to the letter, a function that takes as argument a reference to a mutable data structure (such as a native Array) is not pure:

> Its return value is the same for the same arguments (**no variation with** local static variables, non-local variables, **mutable reference arguments** or input streams from I/O devices).

### Equivalence

Although this clearly says "no variation with mutable reference arguments", we could maybe say this is open to interpretation and depends on the meaning of *"same"* and *"variation"*. There are different definitions possible, and so we enter the area of opinion. Quoted from the paper your referred to:

> There is not a single obviously right answer to these questions. Determinism is thus a parameterized property: **given a definition of what it means for arguments to be equivalent**, a method is deterministic if all calls with **equivalent** arguments return results that are indistinguishable from within the language

The *functional purity* proposed in the same paper, uses the following definition of equivalence:

> Two sets of object references are considered equivalent if they result in identical object graphs

So with that definition, the following two arrays are considered equivalent:

```
let a = [1];
let b = [1];
```

But this concept can not really be applied to JavaScript without adding more restrictions. Nor to Java, which is the reason why the authors of the paper refer to a trimmed-down language, called Joe-E:

> objects have identity: conceptually, they have an “address”, and we can compare whether two object references point to the same “address” using the `==` operator. This notion of object identity can expose nondeterminism.

Illustrated in JavaScript:

```js
const compare = (array1, array2) => array1 === array2;

let arr = [1];
let a = compare(arr, arr);
let b = compare(arr, [1]);
console.log(a === b); // false
```

As the two calls return a different result, even though the arguments had the same shape and content, we should conclude (with this definition of equivalence) that the above function `compare` is not pure. While in Java you can influence the behaviour of the `==` operator (Joe-E forbids calling `Object.hashCode`), and so avoid this from happening, this is not generally possible in JavaScript when comparing objects.

### Unintended side effects

Another issue is that JavaScript is not strongly typed, and so a function cannot be certain that the arguments it receives are what they are intended to be. For instance, the following function looks pure:

```
const add = (a, b) => a + b;
```

But it can be called in way to give side effects:

```js
const add = (a, b) => a + b;

let i = 0;
let obj = { valueOf() { return i++ } };
let a = add(1, obj);
let b = add(1, obj);
console.log(a === b); // false
```

The same problem exists with the function in your question:

```js
const f = (arr) => arr.length;

const x = { get length() { return Math.random() } };
let a = f(x);
let b = f(x);
console.log(a === b) // false
```

In both cases the function unintentionally called an impure function and returned a result that depended on it. While in the first example it is easy to still make the function pure with a `typeof` check, this is less trivial for your function. We can think of `instanceof` or `Array.isArray`, or even some smart `deepCompare` function, but still, callers can set a strange object's prototype, set its constructor property, replace primitive properties with getters, wrap the object in a proxy, ...etc, etc, and so fool even the smartest equality checkers.

### Pragmatism

As in JavaScript there are just too many "loose ends", one has to be pragmatic in order to have a useful definition of "pure", as otherwise almost nothing can be labelled pure.

For example, in practice many will call a function like `Array#slice` pure, even though it  suffers from the problems mentioned above (including related to the special argument `this`).

### Conclusion

In JavaScript, when calling a function pure, you will often have to agree on a contract on how the function should be called. The arguments should be of a certain type, and not have (hidden) methods that could be called but that are impure.

One may argue that this goes against the idea behind "pure", which should *only* be determined by the function definition itself, not the way it eventually might get called.

Comment: Thanks! Good demonstration with the `compare` function. I guess in practice, I'd be fine calling that one impure then...

Comment: The Wikipedia article you quoted already notes: "*Some authors, particularly from the imperative language community, use the term "pure" for all functions that just have the above property 2*", which is still quite useful. So as long as you don't mutate the mutable argument (and no one else does) your function is still pure.

Comment: Also the part that refers to "*mutable reference arguments*" has been added [in these edits](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pure_function&action=historysubmit&type=revision&diff=856004033&oldid=850378830) and is not backed by a quotation from literate. There is also [quite some discussion on the talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Pure_function#Alternate_usage_of_the_term).